# Lemur for iPad?

Tags: ipad, controller

Did any of you use the Lemur from jazzmutant in the past and have you tried the [Lemur](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lemur/id481290621?mt=8) for Ipad? This is just what my ipad has been waiting for, so i'll try it out as soon as work slow down for the holidays. Yaaay!

Comment: I really want to buy one. What do you want to use?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried it, bought it, and it's worth it. I would have bought it just for the physics aspect alone, but the potential is pretty great, if you ask me - not least because of the scripting.

Comment: Cool! Do you use wired midi or osc?

Answer (score 0):

It's the bomb. Very pleased here. Between Lemur and Konkreet Performer, I'm all set on MIDI control.

Comment: Yup, thats what i'm using too. Konkreet performer is really nice for some tasks!

Answer (score 0):

@Tommy-Jansen Not sure if this reply is ending up where it's supposed to, but I've actually only tested it with Wireless(!) MIDI for now, and I'm surprised how well it works.

However, if you want really tight control, I guess you should go for something like the iRig MIDI interface, and perhaps use OSC.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it out with the alesis io dock and see what happens. Then i will have two pres for contact mics etc too...